# Question about regularized time series results

Tags: time-series, interpretation, regularization

I have DowJones dataset containing 30 stocks from 1990-2000. I have chosen IBM as response (y) and  ran a time-dependent regularized regression (similar to lasso). The following plot shows the result. I am confused about the density plots. So my question is:

Is the density plot correct? How it is possible to get two densities that are sharper than the density of y?

[image]